# How do I change the tab stop length for a textbox in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I am making a code editor program for an old pocket PC I have, and I want to be able to change the size of the `\t` character in a multi-line textbox.

I have looked for a really long time and I found this `EM_SETTABSTOPS` which I am not entirely sure how to use that but I think it is what I need to use. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: If that is a rich edit control, then yes, the windows control will listen for the message and set the tab stops accordingly. If you are using C# then this will be unsafe code or a dll import.

Comment: SendMessage(tbMain.Handle, EM_SETTABSTOPS, 1, new int[] { width * 69});

Comment: where would I put that then? Edit: It's also a plain textbox not a rich textbox

Comment: I would imagine in your main app that creates the tbMain.

Comment: [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int wParam, int[] lParam);

Comment: ooh, so tbMain would be where the name of my text box goes. What is this dllimport thing?

Comment: That loads the Native Win32 API that contains the code for textbox messaging and stuff. It sends messages to your textbox within the main form's message loop in your windows application.

Comment: will that work when run on an old pocket pc?

Comment: If it is win ce then yes it should.

Comment: ok that gave me a ton of errors. Where exactly do I put what where? my textbox is named txtInput

Comment: I was able to find this - it is not TexBox and TabStop specific but it should help make your program compile --> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bbe54286-defc-41f3-bad3-c1a7d780af3f/sendmessage-to-window?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

In your form class code:

```
private const UInt32 EM_SETTABSTOPS = 0x00CB;
private const int unitsPerCharacter = 4;

[DllImport("CoreDll.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref IntPtr lParam);
```

then add a function

```
public static void SetTextBoxTabStopLength(TextBox tb, int tabSizeInCharacters)
{
    // 1 means all tab stops are the the same length
    // This means lParam must point to a single integer that contains the desired tab length
    const uint regularLength = 1;

    // A dialog unit is 1/4 of the average character width
    int length = tabSizeInCharacters * unitsPerCharacter;

    // Pass the length pointer by reference, essentially passing a pointer to the desired length
    IntPtr lengthPointer = new IntPtr(length);
    SendMessage(tb.Handle, EM_SETTABSTOPS, (IntPtr)regularLength, ref lengthPointer);
}
```

Then, after InitializeComponents(), call the function with your multiline textbox.

Source: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage